# Can someone please help me to understand the statistics used in this code in R?

Tags: r, t-test

I'm trying to compare the CCS class between two groups, which is a tool to assess chest pain severity graded by physicians on a scale of 1-4 with a higher number indicating greater severity.I was given the following code to generate a stripchart but I don't understand what it means. In particular I don't know why a t-test and Wilcox test was performed, and what the alpha=0.2 indicates.

[image]

Also, is there a statistical reason as to why this is a better method of plotting than using a bar chart?

Comment: Hi Stania, please do not post an image of code - it is easier for you and the community to copy/paste the code instead. Also, this is not the right community to ask questions on how to interpret statistical results. To answer your last question, the statistical field does not point to any particular preference for one data visualization over another. While there are preferences, they are more from a readability aspect than a statistical aspect.

Answer (score 3):

Obviously we can't second-guess what the person who wrote that code is, but:

> I don't know why a t-test and Wilcox test was performed

Often this is done when the assumptions of the t-test are not met, or there is a question mark about them.

> what the alpha=0.2 indicates

This is a parameter to `ggplot2::geom_point` which controls the opacity of the points.

> is there a statistical reason as to why this is a better method of plotting than using a bar chart?

No, this is a matter of personal preference and the requirements of the particular analysis that is being undertaken.